# #define is not propagated from main program to class.cpp?

Tags: c++, class, arduino

If I comment out the #define line from WotClass.h I got compile error: `WotClass.cpp:7: error: 'BFLM_DEFINE' was not declared in this scope`

Isn't it suppose to be scope independent? Or is the problem in the order?

WotClass.h

```
#ifndef WOTCLASS_H
#define WOTCLASS_H

#define BFLM_DEFINE 1 // if commented out then compile fails.

class WotClass{
    public:
        WotClass();
        int foo();
    private:
};

#endif
```

WotClass.cpp

```
#include "WotClass.h"

WotClass::WotClass(){}

int WotClass::foo(){
    return BFLM_DEFINE;
}
```

Test.ino

```
#define BFLM_DEFINE 1 // This is before including class
#include "WotClass.h"

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println(BFLM_DEFINE);
    WotClass x;
    Serial.print(x.foo());
}

void loop(){}
```

Comment: Remove the define from Test, and include it in the header WotClass.h. The cpp only includes the header, which has no define, therefore it fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the compilation of `WtoClass.cpp`:

- First, the preprocessor pulled in `WotClass.h`. Since you commented out the `#define`, this means that `WotClass.h` does not define `BFLM_DEFINE`.
- Not sure what is `Test.ino`, but, at least from your code, it has no bearing on the compilation of `WotClass.cpp`.

So, when compiling this source, `BFLM_DEFINE` is indeed undefined. It's possible that it is defined in some other source file, but that is irrelevant for this compilation unit. This is exactly what the compiler is telling you:

```
WotClass.cpp:7: error: 'BFLM_DEFINE' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Test.ino is the main program for Arduino.

Comment: Ah, got it - still, it is akin to another source file. Different compilation unit.

Answer (score 2):

The compilation of `WotClass.cpp` fails. While compiling this file the compiler can obtain the `BFLM_DEFINE` identifier only from the `WotClass.h` header. And if it is not defined there the compilation fails.

Comment: I've been told that firstly, the Compiler puts all files into single row of text, based on the `#include`s and then it compiles from top to bottom. That's why I tried to use  `#define BFLM_DEFINE` right before including the `WotClass.h` in the main program - It works this way in the classic asp (I'm more VBA guy). Does it mean that firstly it compiles the classes and then it goes through the main program? That would make a sense why putting `#define` before `#include` in the Test.ino does not have any effect.

Comment: @Combinatix The compiler usually compiles *.cpp files independently.